# Does MS Office really support cmyk colors

Tags: color, cmyk

Does MS Office really support cmyk colors although it is shown in fly out menu in colors but some tutorials say it's just to make us happy.

Comment: AFAIK Microsoft Office software doesn't support CMYK

Comment: To me, this is like asking "can I use a chisel to tighten flathead screws?". Regardless of whether the answer is yes or no, it isn't the appropriate tool for the job.

Answer (score 2):

It seems not even Publisher supports CMYK anymore...

Your question, in reality, makes me wonder. Why would someone need a CMYK process which should be a very specific workflow, on an application that does not even states clearly if you can even use it?

Using an application that has not this specific workflow is fooling yourself thinking that you actually are doing it right.

A CMYK file does not just need to be sent as "CMYK"... It needs to be calibrated and profiled for... Should I repeat this? A specific workflow, print situation, type of paper.

If you really need to have CMYK use a suitable program. If you want a free one, use Scribus. Do not use any MS application for that.

Comment: So your answer to the question asked is "no". ... right? Philosophical diversions aside?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Word does not support CMYK images directly in its files. Word uses the RGB color format, but there is a workaround to this problem.

1. Save your Word file as a PDF. Printers like PDFs.
2. Ask your printer if he has Adobe Acrobat or a proprietary software that can convert an RGB color scheme PDF to the CMYK required for printing. This is likely because PDFs are common in the commercial printing industry.

Comment: Cave canem: remember that 'printer' in English can mean both 'person who owns a company that uses large digital printers or offset presses to create prints on paper and stock' and 'device in my office that is hooked up to my computer that spits out paper using ink cartridges or toner'. That last category usually dislikes CMYK.

Comment: There's a couple of traps. You can put to the Word document RGB colors which are not printable as is due the exessive colorfulness. Of course the printhouse flattens them to printable range, but the result can have lost totally the original impact. It must be checked. Another trap: It's too easy to try to print images which are converted to screen resolution. It creates a mess.